# mapStateToProps returning wrong value to props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-props

This is my code

***Container***

```
class BarContainer extends React.Component{
 return(
   <NextPage 
      foo = {this.props.foo}
   />
 )
 }
const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return  {foo: state.foo}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BarContainer);
```

***Reducer***

```
export default (state = false, action) =>  {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_POST: 
           return true;
        default: return state;
    }
 };
```

The value of state.foo is true but when I called foo in props (this.props.foo) it displayed false.

Comment: You will need to post more information.  What do you your store and reducers look like?

Comment: Looks like your entire state tree will simply be `true`. I think you want `return {...state, foo: true}` under `ADD_POST`. And initialize it to `{foo: false}` not simply `false`

Comment: What does your action function look like for `foo`? You might have forgotten to `dispatch` it.